# How to Detect Invalid Pattern Lock Entry in Android

Tags: android

I want to develop an Android App that will perform some action when a user enter invalid pattern lock or pin code while unlocking the mobile. I don't know much about it. Any body can guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `DeviceAdminReceiver` set to handle the `ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED` events, which your receiver would handle in `onPasswordFailed()`. You can read more about the device admin APIs at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Answer (score -1):

Edited:
I think it is possible, but the screen lock runs on it's own sandbox environment.
These links may help you.

[Android Listener for Wrong Lock-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274021/android-listener-for-wrong-lock-pattern)

[Android pattern input in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743068/android-pattern-input-in-application)

Check it out.